# Java - isFull method Circular Array Queue

Tags: java, queue

what is the best way to implement `isFull` method for Circular Array Queue?
Tried to do it like this, but don't think it works.

```
    @Override
    public boolean isFull() {
        return ((rear-front) == -1 || (rear-front) == (size - 1)) ? true :  false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circular queue can be defined as full if the next element to the last element is the first element. Assuming front and rear are the indices of the first and last element you could do something like this.

```
@Override
public boolean isFull() {
    return (rear + 1) % size == front
}
```